# URL re-write not working without www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, no-www

I am having some issues with URL re-writing that I cannot figure out. Here's the problem.

This URL **IS NOT** redirecting properly:
`http://domain.com/index.php?en=oldpage`

HOWEVER, this URL **IS** redirecting properly:
`http://www.domain.com/index.php?en=oldpage`

The only difference in the url that is not redirecting properly is the absence of the `www.`

Here is the re-write I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^en=oldpage
RewriteRule ^(index.php/|)$ /newpage.html? [R=301,L]
```

I also have this re-write **BEFORE** other re-writes, to handle url's without "www.":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Why will it not re-direct without the "www." ? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you define `not redirecting properly`? Does it mean that or not redirecting at all? Do you have the rules in the same order as you've put them here in the question?

Comment: As in not redirecting properly. It just returns user to the homepage (www.domain.com) and not the intended re-write. I have the re-write: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. ... first, before the RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^en=oldpage ... will change in question to be more clear.

Comment: Is your canonical `www` working? The pattern `^(index.php/|)$` in your `RewriteRule` wouldn't match either the example URLs you've posted (with or without `www`), so there is certainly "something else" going on here.

Comment: re-write works fine now. server related issue I was not aware of. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is some code/rule below those rules adding query string back to your URLs.

Try these rules instead based on `THE_REQUEST` variable which doesn't get overwritten:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?en=oldpage [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newpage.html? [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I removed my old re-write and tried your example after clearing cache... Still works the same way as the old re-write. Only works on URL containing "www."